# Get out the students who got Bs in the file using regex

Tags: python, regex

this is my code

```
import re
with open ("E:/College related/Forth Year/Applied Data Science in Python/Course 1/assignments/assignment1/assets/grades.txt", "r") as file: 
    ls = list()
    
    for line in file:
        line.strip()
        ls.append(re.findall('([\w ]+: B)', line))
```

the output contains a lot of empty lists and I don't know why
the output is:

```
[[], ['Bell Kassulke: B'], [], [], [], ['Simon Loidl: B'], ['Elias Jovanovic: B'], [], [], ['Hakim Botros: B'], ['Emilie Lorentsen: B'], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['Jake Wood: B'], ['Fatemeh Akhtar: B'], ['Kim Weston: B'], [], [], [], [], ['Yasmin Dar: B'], [], ['Viswamitra Upandhye: B'], [], ['Killian Kaufman: B'], ['Elwood Page: B'], [], [], ['Elodie Booker: B'], [], [], ['Adnan Chen: B'], [], ['Hank Spinka: B'], [], [], [], [], [], ['Hannah Bayer: B']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that there are lines where you have no matches, and you still add the empty list into the `ls` list of lists.

I have created a "fake" text file on my machine with the following contents:

```py
dddd
Bell Kassulke: B
aaa
Simon Loidl: B
vvv
```

The code you can use is

```py
import re
fpath = r"E:/College related/Forth Year/Applied Data Science in Python/Course 1/assignments/assignment1/assets/grades.txt"
with open(fpath, "r") as file:
     ls = []
     for line in file:
             results = re.findall(r'\w[\w ]*: B', line)
             if results:
                     ls.extend(results)

print(ls)
# => ['Bell Kassulke: B', 'Simon Loidl: B']
```

Note the pattern is now `\w[\w ]*: B` and matches a word char first, no match can start with a space now.

Besides, `line.strip()` used as is on a separate line does nothing, you should assign the result back to `line` if you want to change the variable contents. However, this line is just redundant in your code.